# angularjs bind appended html to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose initial html code is:

```
<div id="first" ng-controller="IndexPageController">

</div>
```

After the page is loaded, it makes some ajax request and appends new html

```
<div id="first" ng-controller="IndexPageController">
   <div id="appended">
      {{data}}
   </div>
</div>
```

My controller

```
MyApp.controller('IndexPageController', ['$scope', '$http',  function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.data="something";
 });
```

**Since the newly created DOM element does not inherit the $scope given to its compiled template. How can i bind the dom element to the controller?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$compile`](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/07/using-compile-in-angular.aspx) service can do just what you need.

Snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("IndexPageController", function ($scope, $http, $compile, $timeout) {
    var htmlText = "<div id=\"appended\">" +
                   "{{data}}" +
                   "</div>";

    var linkFn = $compile(htmlText);
    var content = linkFn($scope);
    $("#first").append(content);
        
    $scope.data = "This should change after 5 seconds...";

    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.data = "Indeed, it is changed";
    }, 5000)
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>

<div>
    <div id="first" ng-controller="IndexPageController">
    </div>
</div>
```

PS.: The resulting HTML will update properly. You can test it by injecting `$timeout` and adding the following piece of code:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.data = "Indeed, it is changed";
}, 5000)
```

Comment: If i change $scope.data , Will it update in  appended html?

Comment: As you can see, `$scope.data` is changed after being appended in the snippet and it shows up properly in the resulting HTML. Updated the answer.

Comment: will it make a difference if i dont use append fucntion and just extract html from compiled dom element like this `content[0].outerHTML` and use this html to append later.

Comment: The way you're adding the value returned by the link function (`content` in this specific example) to the DOM doesn't matter as far as I know. I just used the jQuery `append` function with a HTML string, because that was the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tdtou3au) i have made a fiddle. why ng-click is not binding to the controller scope?

Comment: I updated your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tdtou3au/2/    You didn't have angular.js and jquery.js included as external resources. Also you didn't escape one of the double quotes in the ng-repeat after repeatdata.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102162/discussion-between-vaibhav-chiruguri-and-szabolcs-dezsi).

Answer (score 0):

You should use $compile to link the template and scope